# Adding a jar file into multiple modules in my application

Tags: android

I am developing an android app which has two modules(Android Library). Now I have an external JAR file(EPSON Printer) to manage printing. Now, how I add this JAR file in the project that both modules can share the same file. I don't want to add this file to individually each module because I tried it and it throws me an error : **Program type already present: com.epson.epos2.ConnectionListener.**

Comment: are you using "implementation" tag for adding the jar ?

Comment: @droidev yes, I am using the same

Comment: use "api" instead

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the JAR file following the next steps.
1- In android studio File-->New-->New Module and select Import .JAR/.AAR Package and find the .JAR file.
2- First step create an module for you JAR file. Now create a module dependencies(To the module created in the first step) for each module that you want to use the JAR file.